# How to debug slow argocd refreshing

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

On K8S 1.19 , argoCD 2.1.1, on-premise.

We see very long refresh / reconcilation operations. How to debug this to find the issue?

- CPU/Memory usage is fine
- git sub modules are disabled
- 150 argocd applications
- git projects hosted on the same on-premise infra